# session_start() throws an error while saving variables

Tags: php, html

I have the following FORM:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form method=post action="submit.php">
<!-- 


If the user goes to a different page or refreshes this page it and returns to this page within 2 hours the value that
was originally entered should populate in the respective textbox,radio groups which is not happening...

 -->
    <input type=text value="<?php echo $_SESSION['saveit'][0]; ?>" name="first" />

    <input type=radio value="A" name="acct" <?php echo ($_SESSION['saveit'][1] == A) ? "checked" : "" ?> /> A
    <input type=radio value="B" name="acct" <?php echo ($_SESSION['saveit'][1] == B) ? "checked" : "" ?> /> B

    <input type=radio value="A" name="birt" <?php echo ($_SESSION['saveit'][2] == A) ? "checked" : "" ?> /> A
    <input type=radio value="B" name="birt" <?php echo ($_SESSION['saveit'][2] == B) ? "checked" : "" ?> /> B

    <input type=submit value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
//echo to see what those values are
echo $_SESSION['saveit'][0];
echo "<BR>";
echo $_SESSION['saveit'][1];
echo "<BR>";
echo $_SESSION['saveit'][2];
echo "<BR>"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The following PHP page:

```
<?php
session_start();

//Get the value from form
$first = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['first'])));
$acct = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['acct'])));
$birt = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['birt'])));

$f = isset($first) ? $first : null;
$a = isset($acct) ? $acct : null;
$b = isset($birt) ? $birt : null;

$savearray = array($f,$a,$b);

$_SESSION['saveit'] = $savearray;

//save the value in each individual session (Not using it as I need to save multiple values in ONE session)
//$_SESSION['textbox1'] = isset($first) ? $first : null;
//$_SESSION['radiogroup1'] = isset($acct) ? $acct : null;
//$_SESSION['radiogroup2'] = isset($birt) ? $birt : null;

//set the cookie for each session with the value for 2 hours TTL
//CORRECT syntax to save the ONE session with multiple variable into cookie to be used for upto 2 hours MAX.
//setcookie("textbox1", $first, time()+(3600*2));

//echo test to see what the values are
echo $_SESSION['saveit'][0];
echo "<BR>";
echo $_SESSION['saveit'][1];
echo "<BR>";
echo $_SESSION['saveit'][2];
echo "<BR>";

echo "<a href='http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/testFolder/form.php'>GO TO THE FORM PAGE</a>";
?>
```

- Trying to use the `setcookie()` to store each variable in the session to only be good for 2 hours only, how do I accomplish that?
- When I reload the FORM page, the values are not auto entered using session. How do I fix that?

Comment: Sidenote: `$f = isset($first) ? $first : null;` $first is always set, you assign it a few lines before...Maybe you meant `isset($_POST['first'])` ?

Comment: I am doing it this way to prevent any XSS attack.

Comment: What? I fail to see how XSS attacks are related to checking if an index is set or not...

Comment: `$first = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['first'])));` prevents user from entering a script in the textbox so i sanitze all the inputs before using it?

Comment: I'm not talking about that, but why aren't you checking if $_POST is set before accessing it, and why are you checking if a variable you have declared is set. I meant `if(isset($_POST['first'])) { // do your custom escaping }`

Comment: oooohhhhhh... I get it. Let me edit my code and let me know if it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to call session_start() on the first page.  It must be called on all pages that use session variables, and it should be called before anything else.

Effectively, you never started the session on the page with the form so any values that you set aren't actually being set.

Comment: You are actually correct in that. Thanks! Now how do I make it so it only stays for let's say 3 hours only?

Comment: @SiKni8 You must call time() and store it in a session variable and then use a control structure to check the value of that time and perform the appropriate action -- in this case you would unset the specific session variable or possibly destroy the session altogether and start a new one.